# Querying an XML-Object in Oracle SQL: getting a value of an attribut by specifying another attribut of the object

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xpath, xmltype

I know there are many entries here concerning querying an XML-Object in Oracle SQL. But still, I couldn't find any answer on my question.

I have a SQL table `obj` with some columns incl. a clob object in the XML format (column is called `definition`).

I want to extract a concrete value from the clob.

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <m>
        <i n="Status">0</i>
        <s n="Description">AmountDifference</s>
        <s n="Name">InputvsOutput</s>
        <a n="Variables">
            <m>
                <s n="Name">Formula</s>
                <s n="Value">B-A</s>
            </m>
            <m>
                <s n="Name">CriticalDiff</s>
                <s n="Value">abs({B} - {A}) &lt; 10</s>
            </m>
        </a>
    </m>
```

The SQL query should return two values: `Description` and a `Value` where Name = CriticalDiff.

The part of SQL query looks like this:

```
CAST(
CASE WHEN obj.definition is not null then
       UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE(
                XMLTYPE(obj.definition).
                EXTRACT('//s[@n="Description"]/text()')
                .getStringVal() )
END as varchar(200)) as "Rule Expression"
, obj.definition as rule_xml
```

The CAST block is working fine, but I wonder how to transform the last command in the similar way, so that I get a value by its name (= CriticalDiff).

The difficulty I face is that there are two similar elements (m) with the same attribute names (Name, Value).

Any ideas how I can get a "Value"-attribute from "CriticalDiff" ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
WITH obj AS (
SELECT q'[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <m>
        <i n="Status">0</i>
        <s n="Description">AmountDifference</s>
        <s n="Name">InputvsOutput</s>
        <a n="Variables">
            <m>
                <s n="Name">Formula</s>
                <s n="Value">B-A</s>
            </m>
            <m>
                <s n="Name">CriticalDiff</s>
                <s n="Value">abs({B} - {A}) &lt; 10</s>
            </m>
        </a>
    </m>]' as definition FROM dual
) SELECT 
  XMLTYPE( obj.definition ). 
    EXTRACT('//s[@n="Description"]/text()').getStringVal() as Description,
  XMLTYPE( obj.definition ). 
    EXTRACT('//m/s[@n="Name" and text() = "CriticalDiff"]/text()').getStringVal() as Name,
  UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE(XMLTYPE( obj.definition ). 
    EXTRACT('//m/s[@n="Name" and text() = "CriticalDiff"]/../s[@n="Value"]/text()').getStringVal()) as Value
FROM obj;
```

---

```
DESCRIPTION      |NAME         |VALUE               |
-----------------|-------------|--------------------|
AmountDifference |CriticalDiff |abs({B} - {A}) < 10 |
```

---

Another version of xpath that also works:

```
 EXTRACT('//m[s[@n="Name" and text() = "CriticalDiff"]]/s[@n="Value"]/text()').getStringVal()) as Value
```